# Scrollable DIV that adjusts with page width

Tags: css, html, position

I have a DIV that I want to be scrollable, but the problem is that I'm using position: fixed; and the DIV doesn't adjust it's position with the rest of the page; thus disappearing on small resolutions. Any suggestions would be wonderful.

Here's the current DIV:

```
<div style="
display: block; 
top: 200px; 
left: 1500px; 
width: 130px; 
position: fixed; 
border: 1px solid rgb(136, 136, 136); 
padding: 10px; 
text-align: center; 
font-weight: bold; 
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
background-color:#FFFFFF;
">
```

Comment: Why are you using such a huge `left`? Will `right` not work better?

Comment: `Any suggestions would be wonderful` maybe not using a fixed position?

Comment: if you use % for the measurements it keeps it position on the screen.

Comment: @SvenBieder Technically wrong: `left:1000%` or perhaps `left:-1000%` might just hide the element. What you mean is that it is possible to keep it on screen with the proper use of percents.

Comment: @TheZ Sorry that I haven't said it for the dumbest person possible. For sure it means within a percentage seeable in the viewport (0 to 100%). When proper use is not clear, then the answers would all be a novel, because you need to explain from the very basics to the solution

Comment: @SvenBieder Haha, it was more of a joke but serious replies are always welcome! 0 to 100% is still wrong though, `left:100%` probably won't show unless you've got negative margins or children with offset positions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using pixels for top and left properties use percentages.eg:`top:20%` instead of `top:1200px`.  In smaller resolutions your top left values makes your div go out of the screen. Try this

```
display: block; 
top: xx%; 
left: nn%; 
width: mm%; 
position: fixed; 
border: 1px solid rgb(136, 136, 136); 
padding: 10px; 
text-align: center; 
font-weight: bold; 
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
background-color:#FFFFFF;
```

According to your dives sizes adjust your percentage values.
One side note If you are targeting mobile devices you can use media queries too eg.

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
  #myDivId{
   width: 100px; /* or width:10%; */
  }
}
```

Comment: ended up throwing a margin: left in there to keep it from fixed positioning on top of content